# Unexpected blank spaces in Mail body generated via sp_send_cdosysmail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ole-automation, database-mail

I'm facing a strange problem with `sp_send_cdosysmail` OLE Automation. 
I have a store procedure that will convert a temp table into html table and send them as mail body to distribution list.

Problem is when the no of lines are more than 100 *(x 13 columns)* several blank spaces are inserted in between my html table. Inserting spaces between tags and causing alignment issues with table.

for example tag `</td>` changing to `</t d>` thus resulting the cell value to `[cell value]</t d><td style="background-color:blue;">[next cell value]`.

For debugging i have created a string of 10000 characters `aaaaaaaaaa....aaaaaaaa` and i seen that every 990 characters there was a blank space inserted. when they fall between the html tags it creating issues.

[image: Mail Body Screenshot]

*Those spaces not inserted when i'm creating my html table.* `select @MsgBody` returns the html string that has no spaces in between. but when i receive mail every 990 character one space inserted.

OLE Automation DLL `odsole70.dll`

Please let me know is there any way this can be avoided?

Comment: sp_send_dbmail is superior, try that?

Comment: Yes, but in my workstation i have limitations that i cannot configure dbmail. So sticking with sp_send_cdosysmail.